# VBA Finding the distance between columns in excel

Tags: excel, vba, distance

I've decided to ask this question through examples.  I tried to explain the entire project but it seemed confusing if you weren't already working on the same project so here we go.

As a user of the code I'm writing you need to decide which columns you want the program to actually grab and where to write all of the calculations to.  There are nine columns total that the user can play with, though I'll focus on the first four so it doesn't get too complex.

The first two are the columns that my program needs in order to do it's calculations (explained later) and is really the basis for the entire project to run.  Let's call them Data_Before and Data_After.

The next two columns are the calculations done from the information in Data_Before and Data_After.  These two columns are Diff and Percent.  Like the headers suggest Diff is Data_After - Data_Before and Percent is Diff / Data_Before.

As of now the columns have to be right next to each other.  So if Data_Before is in column "A" then Data_After has to appear in "B" with Diff in "C" and Percent in "D".  This is because of my calculations coming from the record macro function.  The code that populates a cell in Diff and Percent are below

```
' Diff column
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]-RC[-2]" 
' Percent column
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]/RC[-3]"
```

Sorry for the weird coloring in the code, the "Diff column" and "Percent column" are comments.  Anyway, here we have the FormulaR1C1 which makes the program inflexible.  The question being, how to do find the distance between the Diff column and the Data_Before or Data_After column so that the user can have the Data_Before in column "A" and Data_After in column "B" but the Diff and Percent columns wherever they want?

Sorry for the length of the question.

Comment: Let's say a user wants to have Diff and Percent in columns X and Y. How are those locations going to be communicated to the program? Put another way: as it is written currently, how did you determine that columns C and D were the correct output columns?

Comment: The excel file that has all of the code in it is not the same file where I'm getting the data.  Sorry, it's hard for me to explain it clearly but in the file with the code the user inputs what column they want everything in.  Example: A user might say "I want the Data_Before to be in column F, Data_After in column G and so on.  I'll put in code to show you how I find which column everything is in.  Code: Dim Data_Before As String ... Set s1excel = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet ... Data_Before = Range("B2").Text.  The user would input the desired column in the B2 cell in the calculations file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only just saw your comment on the set-up of your program after I'd finished the below, hope it can help in some way.

```
Sub InsertDiffPercentCalc(ByVal rngDataBeforeColumn As Excel.Range, ByVal rngDataAfterColumn As Excel.Range, ByVal rngTargetDiffColumn As Excel.Range, ByVal rngTargetPercentColumn As Excel.Range)

' Diff column
rngTargetDiffColumn.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC" & CStr(rngDataAfterColumn.Column) & "-RC" & CStr(rngDataBeforeColumn.Column)
' Percent column
rngTargetPercentColumn.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC" & CStr(rngTargetDiffColumn.Column) & "/RC" & CStr(rngDataBeforeColumn.Column)

End Sub
```

Based on your comment, you can create a parameterless Sub, but in any case you still have to determine the target columns (or at least their addresses) - how are you doing this? *edit* just seen your other comment.

```
Sub InsertDiffPercentCalc()

Dim rngDataBeforeColumn As Excel.Range
Dim rngDataAfterColumn As Excel.Range
Dim rngTargetDiffColumn As Excel.Range
Dim rngTargetPercentColumn As Excel.Range

Set wksSettings = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("<settings sheet name>")
Set wksTarget = Application.Workbooks("<target workbook name>").Sheets("<target sheet name>")

Set rngDataBeforeColumn = wksTarget.Range(wksSetting.range("A2").Value & ":" & wksSetting.range("A2").Value)
Set rngDataAfterColumn = wksTarget.Range(wksSetting.range("B2").Value & ":" & wksSetting.range("B2").Value)
Set rngTargetDiffColumn = wksTarget.Range(wksSetting.range("C2").Value & ":" & wksSetting.range("C2").Value)
Set rngTargetPercentColumn = wksTarget.Range(wksSetting.range("D2").Value & ":" & wksSetting.range("D2").Value)

' Diff column
rngTargetDiffColumn.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC" & CStr(rngDataAfterColumn.Column) & "-RC" & CStr(rngDataBeforeColumn.Column)
' Percent column
rngTargetPercentColumn.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC" & CStr(rngTargetDiffColumn.Column) & "/RC" & CStr(rngDataBeforeColumn.Column)

End Sub
```

where wksSetting is the name of your settings sheet and wksTarget is the name of your target (output) sheet.

Comment: Sorry I'm pretty new to VBA, but I didn't even realize you could put in parameters in the Sub.  I'm not entirely sure how to edit the code the implement that function since there's a total of 9 columns.  I tried to edit this code so that instead of the ByVal ... As Excel.Range as a parameter I made it Dim ... As Excel.Range in the body.  I have the same calculations as you later in my code but I get an error that says "Object variable or With block variable not set" right at the first calculation.  Is there something special about that ByVal?  I got a syntax error when I switched Dim to ByVal

Comment: Don't worry, we're here to help :)
The Sub is designed to be called from another Sub and passed four parameters - the Before/After/Diff/Perc. ranges. Your error is probably caused because you are running the Sub without supplying these parameters. If you wanted it to run without parameters, please see my (edited) answer.

Comment: When I try to run this it gives me a run-time error '424' saying that an Object is required.  the line that gets screwed up is the first Set... which makes me assume all the sets will get a run-time.  I checked my spelling and everything and it all seems to match up to yours, so I'm unsure of what is wrong

Comment: Hi Jesse, this is probably because you do not have these worksheets set up to reference your "settings" and "target" sheets set. You mentioned that you have a settings part where you set the Data_Before and Data_After columns - where is this located? In the workbook containing the VBA code, if so what is the sheet name? What about the target sheet, is this in a separate workbook?

Comment: The settings part is with the code, the target sheet is a completely different workbook

Comment: I've added some parts to the code above. You will need to replace `<settings sheet name>` with the name of the sheet that contains the settings for the columns. I am not sure how you are selecting the target workbook, but in any case you will need to replace `<target workbook name>` with the name of your target workbook and `<target sheet name>` with the sheet that you wish to operate on.

Answer (score 0):

Per your comment, it seems you know exactly where to put the output. Right? So, if column B was data after and column A was data before and the user wanted the diff column in column G, you could use this for your diff formula:

```
Range("G1").Formula = "=B1-A1"
```

Or am I misunderstanding?

## Edit

You're probably after something like this:

```
sheet1.Columns(15).column - sheet1.Columns(13).column ' returns 2
```

You could use that to create an R1C1 formula.

Comment: The problem is that the user can have these columns anywhere.  I wanted to try and make my code flexible enough so that the user can say "the data_before and data_after columns are in Z and AA and I want the calculations done in columns FEM and FEN (really any column is valid)".  I guess I want the locations of where specific cells are to not be hard coded so much as adapt to what the user has said they want the columns to be.  The only real requirement I need from the user is the data_before and data_after columns they specify actually have numbers in them

Comment: Ok, but then we're back to my original question: if your user changes their mind about the output location, how will that be communicated to the program? Named ranges? UserForm? Or will the destination be written in a cell somewhere?

Comment: The destination is written in the excel file that all the code is in (code is within a button).  so in this separate file my column A has cells like "Data_Before" or "Data_After" where column B is the the target columns they'll be in.  So if the user inputs "H" in cell A2 and "I" in cell B2 my code will recognize that and looks for those two cells in the excel file that has the raw data.  sorry, I'm not explaining it very well, but generally the code only knows where everything goes once it starts running, nothing is being hard-coded so that it will be more flexible for the user